# SAS ODS Documentation Syntax Error

Tags: sas, ods

I have many questions regarding the ODS system and am trying to educate myself.  However, I am unable to do so as the SAS documentation example generates an error.

The documentation in question is [Controlling Where Your Output Is Stored](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/67881/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n014ro62pa3xu0n165t2qpffbmiv.htm#p0a6jltms4bk32n1qhe7f3b9bxh8).

The very first example is, verbatim,

```
/* Specify the ODS output path */
filename odsout ".";

goptions reset=all;
ods _all_ close;
ods pdf path=odsout file="mygraph.pdf";
proc gchart data=sashelp.prdsale;
   vbar Product / sumvar=actual;
      title1 "First Quarter Sales in Canada";
      where Quarter=1 and Country="CANADA";
   run;
quit;
ods pdf close;
ods html; /* Not required in SAS Studio */
```

It appears that the `"."` in the `filename` statement is a place holder akin to `"C:\your\file\path\here\"`.

I have replaced that with `"C:\output"`.  When I do this, I get the following error:

```
6    ods pdf path=odsout file="mygraph.pdf";
             ----
             22
             76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, (, ANCHOR, AUTHOR, BACKGROUND, BASE,
              BODY, BOOKMARK, BOOKMARKGEN, BOOKMARKLIST, BOX_SIZING, CLOSE, COLOR, COLUMNS, COMPRESS,
              CONTENTS, CSSSTYLE, DISPLAY, DOM, DPI, EXCLUDE, FILE, FONTSCALE, GFOOTNOTE, GTITLE,
              HOST, KEYWORDS, NAMED_DEST, NEWFILE, NOBACKGROUND, NOBOOKMARKGEN, NOBOOKMARKLIST,
              NOCOLOR, NOCONTENTS, NOGFOOTNOTE, NOGTITLE, NOPDFNOTE, NOTOC, PACKAGE, PCL, PDF,
              PDFMARK, PDFNOTE, PDFTOC, PRINTER, PS, SAS, SELECT, SGE, SHOW, STARTPAGE, STYLE,
              SUBJECT, TEXT, TITLE, UNIFORM.
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Am I doing something wrong or did the author of this example not compile before publishing?

Comment: `.` actually means "here" (the current directory), though for the purposes of the example your explanation works just as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem that `path` option is valid in `ods html`, but is not valid in `ods pdf`, but it doesn't matter because you can specify absolute path in `file` option.

```
ods pdf file="C:\temp\mygraph.pdf";
```